# Non-sliding content and action bar using SlidingMenu library

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using Jeremy Feinstein's SlidingMenu library to implement a sliding menu on the right.

Is there any way to make the menu slide out without displacing/pushing the content view to the side? Currently, when the menu slides out, the content also gets pushed towards either the left or right (depending on which direction the menu is coming out from). I would like to make an implementation where the menu appears from either the left/right but "sits on top" of the content view (content view never moves, the menu view literally flies in and out).

Ive been digging about but there doesnt appear to be a simple function i can call to enable this. Do I have to implement it myself or am I missing something?

Comment: use a frame layout as the mother layout hide the make the menu visible and invissible with animations if you want no need of any library (or use sliding drawer)

Comment: Yeah i was thinking of implementing it that way as an alternative. Was partly hoping there was a simple way of re-using the library since other parts of my project uses the slidingmenu in its default implementation.

Comment: you can make your own library if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to answer my own question! :D

It seems that after looking through the source code of Jeremy Feinstein's SlidingMenu library, what happens is that the library actually "extracts" out our view and then somehow join it together with the sliding-out view. After that, the views are merely scrolled around (I could be mistaken, but i know the extraction of view does occur. As for the way the library accomplishes the scrolling and sliding, i didnt look into it too much.).

So, the answer to my own question is : No, it cannot be done by the library. No simple function available (due to the way the library achieves the sliding effect).

In the end, i opted to use a framelayout with overlapping views. One visible, the other invisible. Then i just change visibility and animate the views.